# I want to see all posts and create new ones in the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started to learn Ruby on Rails. I want that users can create new posts on the same page that shows all posts. Also it would be great if an user could update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going through this tutorial:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

or

http://railsforzombies.org/

Take the form from the `new` view, put it in your `index` view and change the `redirect_to` and `render` in the `create` action to point to the `index` page.

Comment: I know this tutorials but actually I've no time for that. My current idea is to pass get-code to the create-page and use the create-form as static content on the index.page.

Comment: You will actually save yourself a lot of time - and hair pulling - if you go through the rails tutorial book :-)

Answer (score 1):

Learning a language or framework will require reading or researching.

In the most general sense, create a link at the bottom of the list for your posts index action (assuming you are using scaffolding). If what you mean by "on the same page" is you don't have to reload a new page, this will have to be an ajax request link.

The request will map to a controller function, which you will then use unobtrusive javascript to re-render or add onto you list of posts, likely using JQuery.

If none of that made sense: you need to read a book or more online tutorials about Ruby on Rails with Ajax and Unobtrusive Javascript.

Mr. Bates over at railscasts.com has some incredible videos regarding RoR.  It is an indispensable resource.